# laravel composer update fail when trying to update illuminate

Tags: php, laravel-5

When i tried to update illuminate like that but failed.

```
sudo composer.phar require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

it showed that error,

```
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:
```

please help me.

Comment: You mean it doesn't show any messages?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Answer (score 0):

**Illuminate/Html** has been deprecated, you can see it [here](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html). Now as the authors of this package said you should use **laravelcollective/html**

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Then in **config.app** in *providers* array:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

And in *aliases* array in same file:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx but it doesnt.

Comment: still have that problem. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Comment: but at least you installed the similar package without problems, isn't it ? :). Try the solutions provided [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationbindshared) for that error

Comment: the problem is solved by renaming the bindShared() to singleton(). Thx dude

Comment: Good! Glad to hear that, remember to google every error that you face. In most cases you will find a really good explanation and solution.